# How to make jQuery Inputmask work with seconds

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I'm using [Robin Herbots Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) and I'm trying to use the given datetime pattern but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.i-mask-date-time').inputmask('dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss');
```

I can achieve the pattern in the field via

```
 $('.i-mask-date-time').inputmask('99/99/9999 99:99:99', { 
    'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' 
 })
```

but it doesn't include the proper date and time validation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714278/jquery-inputmask-allowing-placeholder-text-to-remain

Comment: @TinhNQ the content in the link doesn't answer my question. Thx by the way

Answer (score 1):

its very simple please read documatation follow theme. link below

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/4.x/README_date.md

and do some changes like below.

'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:ss' change instead of 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss'

i hope this work

Comment: I'm gonna test as soon as I get home from work. I'll accept the answer if it works.