# InputMask js Backspace

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I am using InputMask js plugin for date formatting. And I seem to have an issue with Backspace key. 
Whenever I use Backspace to remove one digit from the date, the actual date gets altered in a wrong way.

I did not found anything regarding this issue, so I started checking the library's code. There's a pretty complicated handling for the 'Backspace' key, so I wasn't able to figure it out.

```
$(".testMask").inputmask("datetime",{
     inputFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

For this example, if I would type in the input 25/05/2019, then go after the digit '1' in the year and pressing Backspace, then the value would look like this: 25/05/209y, I would expect to be 25/05/20y9 because I didn't remove the last digit.

For the same date (25/05/2019), if I would go to the digit '5' in the month and press 'Backspace', then the value looks like this: 25/02/019y. Month is replaced with digit '2' and last digit of the year is replaced with 'y'. In this case, I would expect to look like this: 25/0m/2019

Here is also a JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/06zkdqxn/1/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714278/jquery-inputmask-allowing-placeholder-text-to-remain

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure I can use it in my case. That issue tries to prevent the user to leave placeholder letters in the input. In my case, I want the placeholder to be displayed, but in a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

The Backspace issue has been fixed in the new 5.x beta. 
See related post here: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/2163